# Ultra rapid fire duration

Tags: league-of-legends

As we all know, ultra rapid fire mode is a limited game mode introduced as an April Fool's Day joke, but it is still very fun to play.

How much time do we have to play in this game mode?

Does it use the same queue mmr as normal 5v5 or a different one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer the last question first. Since the number of victories are different on the result screen, I assume the MMR would be different than normal queue. Obviously Riot did no state anything about it.

About the duration, the site clearly say:

> Enjoy U.R.F. until 05:00 CET on April 8th

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can play as much as you want until it's taken out of the game

> Enjoy U.R.F. until 05:00 CET on April 8th

You can also create custom games with it. I've played a bit of 3v3 with it myself.